# Is new keyword is necessary with ObjectID in MongoDB Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, express

I was working on a **Typescript** web project that used **MongoDB** and **ExpressJS**. I used a MongoDB query to find and delete a document from MongoDB using the **HTTP DELETE** method. During the MongoDB query, I got mixed up with a term named **new** and **ObjectID**.
Here are the code snippets:

```
//Without new Keyword
      const resData: DeleteWriteOpResultObject = await data
        .collection("posts")
        .deleteOne({
          _id: ObjectID(req.params.id),
        });


//With new keyword
  const resData: DeleteWriteOpResultObject = await data
    .collection("posts")
    .deleteOne({
      _id: new ObjectID(req.params.id),
    });
```

**Both are working fine as I expected. But I want to know what's the difference between these two**. **Is there any memory-related difference or something else?**

*While googling I got an article also. I am attaching the link* [here](https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/using-typescript-with-mongodb-tutorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the official driver documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.7/classes/ObjectId.html), `ObjectId` is a class which means you need to use `new` to instantiate it.

However, looking at the actual implementation, it will allow itself to be called as a regular function, in which case it will `return new ObjectId(...)`   (so it will instantiate itself automatically).

Comment: I'm not sure when this changed, but this no longer appears to be the case. We had widespread breakages after updating to 5.7.0 because of a lack of `new`.